# Recursive class initialisation in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm building a simple tree data structure that takes some input and creates  nodes in the tree until the input is small enough. That's all well and good (and very simple). For traversal reasons, I want to include a reference to the parent on each node (so I can walk it back "up"), or nil in the case of root. I tried to do this more or less like this (this is, of course, a simpler version—the actual tree is an octree):

```
class Recursive {
    let value: Int
    let child: Recursive?
    weak var parent: Recursive?

    init(value: Int, parent: Recursive? = nil) {
        self.value = value
        self.parent = parent

        if value > 1 {
            self.child = Recursive(value: value-1, parent: self) // fails
        } else {
            self.child = nil
        }
    }
}

var r: Recursive? = Recursive(5)

while r != nil {
    print(r!.value)
    r = r!.child
} // should print 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Of course, this doesn't actually work. It seems you cannot pass "self" as an argument within the init method. I guess this is because of the whole two-step initialisation thing. What's the best (most idiomatic and/or most convenient and/or most performant) approach to this sort of thing in Swift? I've mostly written Python and a bit of C before now, so this Swift stuff is all pretty new to me.

I suppose I *could* write a separate function that initialises the tree, but it seems like it ought to be possible to do it all from the initialisation method. I just can't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can pass `self` to the recursive call only
after it has been *fully initialized* (otherwise the recursively called
function could access an uninitialized property).

A possible solution is to assign the child's parent *after* the
child has been constructed. That allows you to keep `child` as a constant
property:

```
class Recursive {
    let value: Int
    let child: Recursive?
    weak var parent: Recursive?

    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
        if value > 1 {
            self.child = Recursive(value: value - 1)
            // Now `self` is fully initialized!
            self.child?.parent = self
        } else {
            self.child = nil
        }
    }
}
```

And just for fun: The "linked-list traversal" can be done without
forced unwrapping:

```
var r: Recursive? = Recursive(value: 5)
while let node = r {
    print(node.value)
    r = node.child
}
```

and even shorter, with a *constant* list head:

```
let r = Recursive(value: 5)
for node in sequence(first: r, next: { $0.child }) {
    print(node.value)
}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks for the suggestion about using sequence. That's really convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Your `child` parameter should be `var` instead of `let` and it should work. You can also remove the `else` since `child` is `nil` by default (`var` optionals are `nil` by default)

Comment: That does work. But... why? I don't really understand Swift's class instance initialisation. Why can I recursively assign variables but not constants? Good point about the default value for child.

Comment: Because `let` optionals are not initialized with `nil` by default and you are trying to access your instance before being initialized.